# Null in statment

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

frist this is checkinout table

```
select userid , checktime from checkinout where  
     USERID=467 and CHECKTIME>'2014-10-24 00:00:00.000' order by chcktime 

userid  checktime
    467 2014-10-24 02:18:20.000
    467 2014-10-24 17:04:43.000
    467 2014-10-25 02:31:40.000
    467 2014-10-25 17:13:38.000
    467 2014-10-25 20:59:10.000
    467 2014-10-28 02:55:57.000
    467 2014-10-28 17:57:12.000
    467 2014-10-29 17:13:35.000
    467 2014-10-30 02:35:47.000
    467 2014-10-30 17:17:56.000
    467 2014-10-31 03:02:50.000
    467 2014-10-31 17:19:18.000
    467 2014-11-01 02:42:18.000
    467 2014-11-01 17:16:14.000
    467 2014-11-02 02:44:00.000
    467 2014-11-03 17:20:10.000
    467 2014-11-04 02:38:57.000
    467 2014-11-04 17:33:54.000
    467 2014-11-05 02:15:50.000
    467 2014-11-05 17:14:25.000
```

and i have this query

```
SELECT USERID,MIN(checktime) AS InTime,MAX(checktime) AS OutTime
    FROM checkinout
where USERID=467 and CHECKTIME>'2014-10-24 00:00:00.000'
       GROUP BY USERID,DATEDIFF(dd,0,DATEADD(hh,-4,checktime)) 
    HAVING MIN(checktime) <> MAX(checktime)
    AND MAX(DATEADD(hh,-4,checktime))-DATEDIFF(dd,0,DATEADD(hh,-4,checktime)) > '22:00' 
    ORDER BY MIN(checktime) 

userid  InTime                    OutTime
467 2014-10-24 17:04:43.000 2014-10-25 02:31:40.000
467 2014-10-29 17:13:35.000 2014-10-30 02:35:47.000
467 2014-10-30 17:17:56.000 2014-10-31 03:02:50.000
467 2014-10-31 17:19:18.000 2014-11-01 02:42:18.000
467 2014-11-01 17:16:14.000 2014-11-02 02:44:00.000
467 2014-11-03 17:20:10.000 2014-11-04 02:38:57.000
467 2014-11-04 17:33:54.000 2014-11-05 02:15:50.000
```

what i need to have the null in the output like

```
userid  InTime                  OutTime
    467 Null                    2014-10-24 02:18:20.000     
    467 2014-10-24 17:04:43.000 2014-10-25 02:31:40.000
    467 2014-10-25 17:13:38.000 Null
    467 2014-10-25 20:59:10.000 Null
    467 2014-10-28 17:57:12.000 Null
    467 Null                    2014-10-28 02:55:57.000
    467 2014-10-29 17:13:35.000 2014-10-30 02:35:47.000
    467 2014-10-30 17:17:56.000 2014-10-31 03:02:50.000
    467 2014-10-31 17:19:18.000 2014-11-01 02:42:18.000
    467 2014-11-01 17:16:14.000 2014-11-02 02:44:00.000
    467 2014-11-03 17:20:10.000 2014-11-04 02:38:57.000
    467 2014-11-04 17:33:54.000 2014-11-05 02:15:50.000
```

and this table is for finger print check in and check out and the user id 467 is have shift from 5 pm to 2 am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close!

Here's a quick fix (not tested, but I hope you get the idea):

```
Select USERID
    ,MIN(Case When convert(time, checktime) > '12:00:00' Then checktime End) AS InTime
    ,MAX(Case When convert(time, checktime) <= '12:00:00' Then checktime End) AS OutTime
From checkinout
Where USERID=467 and CHECKTIME>'2014-10-24 00:00:00.000'
Group By USERID, DATEDIFF(dd,0,DATEADD(hh,-4,checktime)) 
Order By 2
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with your current data structure.

Your current table is a relation from `userid -> checktime`, and now you want somehow to split `checktime` into `intime` and `outtime`, but that's impossible without more information.

You want to group by day, that's fine. If you find 2 `checktime` entries for a single day, you know the lower one is `intime` and the higher one is `outtime`. But if there's only a single `checktime` entry, you can't really tell if it's `in` or `out`. The only way would be to say "if it's a single `checktime` and it's before 12:00:00, then it must be `intime`. if it's after 12:00:00 it must be `outtime`".

In other words: How would you decide, if `intime = null` or `outtime = null` if there's a single `checktime` entry for a given day?

Another point is: How would you handle 3 (or more) `checktime` entries on a single day?

Comment: Mr @Benjamin M  let us say the first  checktime  in between 4 pm and 8 pm be intime and last checktime between 1 am and 4 am be outime but if we have intime and no out time put intime and out time null can we do that